# Amcharts change opacity of many elements on hover

Tags: hover, amcharts, chord-diagram

I have the following ChordDiagram https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/4a8wtos6/.
I need to change the opacity of some elements when hovering other elements.

On hovering a node, opacity of all elements except the related links/nodes must be change from 1 to 0.5.
For instance, when hovering "C" node, all nodes and links opacity must be changed to 0.5 except the links C->A, B->C, C->E and the related nodes (C, A, B and E).

On hovering a link, opacity of all elements except the source & destination nodes must be change from 1 to 0.5.
For instance, when hovering link C->A, opacity of all elements except the nodes A & C and the link C->A must be change from 1 to 0.5.

I have seen documentation when opactity of the hovered element itself can be changed with the following code but nothing about changing all the elements opacity :

```
var hoverState = chart.nodes.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.opacity = 0.3;
```

How can I achieve this automatically ?